# Data Binding in 3 layered architecture?

Tags: asp.net

Does data binding fit in a 3 layered architecture?  Is dropping a grid-view on a web form and binding it to a LinkDataSource or SQLDataSource considered bad?  The way I see it, that's the Presentation Layer talking to the Data Access Layer.  I once heard a "professional developer" say never ever do this, so what's the alternative if you shouldn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are doing is ok if it is a small project, but if you want your app. to have flexibility to support Windows/ Web in future then you must use Layers.

Please follow this link http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/1566-n-Tier-Architecture-Asp.aspx

You should have a middle tier between Presentation and Data Access layers, the middle tier is pulled out from the presentation tier and, as its own layer, it controls an application’s functionality by performing detailed processing.

**The main task of Business layer is business validation and business workflow.**

When you build your business logic components into an SDK, you are effectively disconnecting it from your Web application, and any input validation that it performs. Therefore, your business logic components are the last line of defense to make sure that only valid values make it into your database.

Answer (score 1):

Databinding is, of course, necessary to effectively dispay data.

Tooling is great and can boost productivity. It is equally important to understand what the tooling is generating, even at a basic level, in order to be able to effectively utilize the generated code.

The reaction you describe seems a bit extreme. If a wizard can generate some code that works for ya, then use it. If you don't understand the generated code then that is the next priority; learn about what it is doing and why. In the meantime, you have a page that people can put eyes on regardless of how it got there.

I am a bit pragmatic when it comes to tools. You do what you have to do. But, if after [insert appropriate internship length] you are still using code gen and cannot customize or fix it then you (as in the royal you, not the you you) are being lazy or stupid or both. ;-)

OT:(almost) Never say never unless you want to lessen the impact of what you are trying to communicate.

my 2 pesos.

Answer (score 1):

When you're doing a small project or a prototype, go with the LINQDataSource or SQLDataSource. However, the downsides of those data sources are serious enough for you to think hard if they are appropriate. If your doing a multi-layered or multi-tear architecture, they simply don't fit. But even if your architecture isn't that strict, you should ask yourself how big this application is going to be and how likely it is going to be that you will make changes to the system in the future. How much time it is going to take you when you want to make a change to the database?

I've seen projects were the developers used those data sources, because those were the constructs that were used in those nice ASP.NET video's. However, when the projects grown from prototypes to big production applications (yes, I’ve seen it happen, the prototype seemed good enough), the lack of compile time support (your queries are defined in markup!) made it very hard to do any change to the system.

When you need to make a change to the system, that will be the time that you’ll see that the cost of the change is a magnitude bigger than the time you saved by flattering your architecture.